# Enable Nuxt Devtools on production build

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Currently I enable the devTools generally in our `nuxt.config.ts`

```
devtools: {
    enabled: true,
  },
```

However, this only seems to work whenever I run `nuxt dev`.

Is there a way to view the Nuxt DevTools as well with a build created by running `nuxt build`?